# Broad cast receiver to listen a particular package removing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broad cast receiver for my application which listens uninstalling a package, and then it will start a transparent activity as requirement. (My application itself have an option to uninstall a package that is related to my other application only) I registered my receiver in manifest as follows.

```
<receiver android:name=".PackageRemoveReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/> 
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My receiver class is as follows.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    this.context = context;
    boolean replacing = intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_DATA_REMOVED, false);
    Log.d("Log","getting receivers");
    if(replacing){
        ......
                    ......


        startActivity(context);
    } 

   private void startActivity(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    Intent i = new Intent(context, TransparentActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);

}
```

so, after listening the intent it is opening my activity. Up to here it is working fine.

But, whenever am doing something like uninstalling different applications (other than my applications ) from settings, it always listening and opens my transparent activity.

I want to run broad cast only , whenever a particular package removed. Is it possible, if yes how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the package name in `onReceive()`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getDataString().equals("package:your.package.name")) {
        ...
}
```

Comment: can make this receiver work inside my activity only? means, if the uninstallation done from my application only, i want the effect of receiver. Because after closing my application, if i uninstall the other application, then my application is opening and showing the new activity.(by listening the receiver). what to do?